# Eliminate the appearance of a dip when plotting increasing data with smoothing

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a data set in which Y is an increasing function of X.  Here is the data:

```
5  | 0.1
10 | 0.789
15 | 147.5
20 | 216.5
25 | 276.5
```

I create an XY (Scatter) Chart with Smooth Lines:

[image]

Because the first two points are very close in Y value, and not characteristic of the distribution of the other points, the smooth line option displays a 'dip' between those two points.

How can I plot this with a smoothed line that estimates the curve on which the data lie without having it include a dip?

Comment: Is adding a trendline while hiding the main graph an acceptable option?

Comment: @k.Rmth can u see the data i added to help me determine the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "dip" down?

Comment: @DavidPostill the second image of the search results from google image 

search 'dip graph'

Comment: Hmm. This is what I get in LibreOffice Calc http://imgur.com/sR1lX0B - I don't get any "dips"

Comment: Use a log scale for your y values?

Comment: @DavidPostill I am supposed to get curved graph

Comment: Please upload an image of what your graph looks like to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get a link you can share. [Edit] your question to include this link and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill it looks like this " U /" connect the / to the right end of U

Comment: It's because you don't have enough data points to plot a smooth curve

Comment: Try this http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2045-excel-smooth-line-graph.html

Comment: @DavidPostill do u know how i can make the first 2 points straight and keep the rest curved?

Comment: No I don't ... but it's still not very clear what you are trying to do. Why don't you use a log scale for the y-axis (2nd column of data) then your "points" will not be close together.

Comment: Two thoughts.  1) Are you sure that the dip doesn't really represent the process creating the points (do you know the process and know that there cannot be a dip)?  2) The problem is that the curve-fitting algorithm isn't smart enough.  You would need to add points where you think they should go.  At the X value of the bottom of the dip, add a data point with your estimated value.  The curve will probably distort a little somewhere else, so add an estimated value at the worst deviation.  Keep doing that until Excel has enough points to plot a curve that reflects what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you willing to manipulate (fudge) your data to get the desired chart? 
I was able to add one point:

```
5     0.1
9.9   0.7
10    0.789
15    147.5
20    216.5
25    276.5
```

and the chart changed to this:

[image]

Comment: No need to fudge the data, simply repeat the second point.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from looking prettier, there's usually no reason to use smoothed lines. Not if you're plotting real data. The smoothing hides the fact that you only have a handful of data points. I'm always a little suspicious (no offense) when I see a chart with smoothed lines, and I always recommend that people not use them.

The most honest way to plot the points is with markers connected with straight line segments.

[image: Straight Lines With Markers]

If you omit the markers but just show the straight lines, you get the following, which still has a slight indication of the scarcity of data.

[image: Straight Lines Without Markers]

If you absolutely *must* use smoothed lines, you can eliminate the dip without actually fudging your data (as suggested by @scott), by merely duplicating the second data pair.

[image: Smoothed but Without the Dip]

Not really different from the previous graph, with straight segments.

---

Edit by fixer1234:  Understanding why this works is as useful as knowing that it works, and the reason isn't necessarily intuitive.  **Quick, simplified explanation:**

I'll refer to the five XY data points as the letters A through E.  Excel creates the smoothed line by fitting a curve to (a rolling), three points at a time: ABC, BCD, CDE.  When points A, B, and C are in a pattern like this example, forcing the curve through those points can produce an unexpected shape, like the dip.

Adding a duplicate second point means that Excel is fitting ABB, BBC, BCD, CDE.  The three points ABB have the same effect as fitting a line between two points, A and B, because the two Bs are essentially the same point for curve-fitting purposes.  Similarly, BBC is equivalent to fitting a line between B and C.  Fitting a line between two points gives you a straight line with those endpoints.

Note that while this solves the problem of graphing the data, it still introduces fake data.  The value is identical to the real data, so it doesn't involve estimating intermediate points, but be aware that the added point can still throw off calculations that use the data for a purpose other than graphing.

Comment: I find that to be non-intuitive.  Can you explain why it works?

Comment: I don't know the exact details, but a colleague of mine fleshed it out a long time ago. Excel fits a bezier to two adjacent segments or three adjacent points (or does something equivalent). Apparently if two adjacent points have the same coordinates, these points behave like endpoints of a set of points.

Comment: @fixer1234 - That's fine. I thought a comment was sufficient, but maybe more people will read the amendment. Thanks for the comment too.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple fix is:

Format Axis > Reset Bounds 'Minimum' to 0 > Draw a straight line connecting the missing line.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I had a data set in which there was an unexpected dip appearing in my line chart, even though the numbers were all increasing. It turned out that the data (revenue) was supposed to be in date order, but some of the dates were not in the correct order (i.e., a sale in August came earlier in the data set than a sale in July). This was because of the difference between so-called "accrual accounting" and "cash accounting." In one, you book the revenue when it is "earned" and in the other, you don't book it until the payment arrives. Often, such dates result in data that is out of order. So, once I corrected it to make sure that not just sales revenue were ascending, but the date field was also ascending, it fixed the unexpected dips in my curve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).