# Using a Trendline formula to get Values for any given X in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So basically i have a graph with lots of different X values, but i'm trying to organize it in 0.1 intervals. Below is an example of my problem:

This is an example of what i have:

- X    |  Y
- 0.1 |   2
- 0.12 |  4
- 0.25  | 8
- 0.34 |  4
- 0.43 |  6
- ...

This is what i'm trying to accomplish (? marks):

- X    |  Y
- 0.1  |  ?
- 0.2  |  ?
- 0.3  |  ?
- 0.4  |  ?
- 0.5   | ?
- ...

Is any way of creating an automatic process, using trend lines, to get the Y values of X's in 0.1 intervals instead of the orginial ones? Thanks in advance for any anwsers. Cheers!

Comment: Your Y values are all over the place (not a simple function), so the short answer is that your data is too complicated for an automated process.  Unless you know something about the process that produced the data, there isn't even a good way to do it manually that's both simple and reliable.  If you're a glutton for punishment, http://superuser.com/questions/984959/how-to-interpolate-intermediate-values-for-arbitrary-data-in-excel-2013 is a somewhat related question with several very long answers that go into detail.

Comment: You're not looking for a trendline. You want to interpolate. But a simple linear model seems inappropriate given your data example.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the linest() function, which returns an array.  We use the INDEX() to pull the individual parts of the array:

```
=(INDEX(LINEST($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6),1,1)*D2)+INDEX(LINEST($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6),1,2)
```

D2 contains my x of `.1`.  So I put this in E2 and copied down.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your anwser! I forgot to mention in the OP, but each pair of X's form an independent linear function, for example: you have a linear equation for (X=0.1 Y=2 |X=0.12 Y=4), then a different one for (X=0.12 Y=4|X=0.25 Y=8); (X=0.25 Y=8|X=0.34 Y=4) and so on.. But thanks anyway @Scott Craner

Comment: @Tomassilveira then that is not the trendline.  The trend line is the dotted line in the graph.